# Optimize sparse softmax cross entropy with L2 regularization

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, loss-function

I was training my network using `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` as the classification function in the last layer and everything was working fine.

I simply added a L2 regularization over my weights now and my loss is not getting optimized anymore. What can be happening?

```
reg = tf.nn.l2_loss(w1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(w2)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(y, logits)) + reg*beta
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

[image]

Comment: did you try scaling down your l2 loss?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer with certainty given the provided information, but here is a possible cause:

[`tf.nn.l2_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss) is computed as a sum over the elements, while your cross-entropy loss is reduced to its mean (c.f. `tf.reduce_mean`), hence a numerical unbalance between the 2 terms.

Try for instance to divide each L2 loss by the number of elements it is computed over (e.g. `tf.size(w1)`).

Comment: That's true I should have realized about this (though I'm using a beta parameter and this effect should be smoothed with low values of it).